# Simulation of android webview

Tags: android, testing, webview

I'm new to android..... 
I have to automate some user actions in webview. 
Robotium is not supporting user action in webview..... as far as i know... 
Can anyone please shed some light on...

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same thing but didn't find anything yet.

AFAIK, selenium allows you to test web-based apps in Adnroid but don't think it can automate native apps. Check out this [lecture](http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/testing-your-mobile-apps-with-selenium-2-and-frank/)